# Can't print PDF in Safari since Yosemite

Tags: safari, pdf, printing

I can't print a PDF in Safari. I hit Print but nothing happens. This never happened until I downloaded Yosemite.

Comment: Does Print works elsewhere?

Comment: To clarify for me. You have a PDF open in Safari and you try to print it?

Comment: When you "hit print" are you referring to the general Print command or with the printer icon that will pop up at the foot of the PDF page displayed in Safari?

Comment: I've started seeing this since we upgraded, too. Safari users with in-browser PDFs can try to print (either cmd+p, File->Print, or Print buttons inside the browser window--if they have Acrobat set to handle in-browser PDFs). No print dialog comes up and nothing is sent to the printer.